# Android AlertDialog gives the error java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, spinner, android-alertdialog

i need to show a Dialog in my application. In this dialog there is a Spinner. So i use this code to show the dialog and fill the Spinner:

```
public class setup4 extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setup4);
}

//On bottone setup 4
public void onSetup4bottone(View v)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder customDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    customDialog.setTitle("Aggiungi ora scolastica");
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.aggiungi_ora,null);
    customDialog.setView(view);

    List<String> materie = new ArrayList<String>();
    materie.add("ADASDASD"); materie.add("LOLOLOL");

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.aggiungi_ora_materia);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, materie);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    customDialog.show();
}
}
```

onSetup4bottone is the click-event of a simple button that must invoke the Dialog.
I can't understand why i get the java.lang.NullPointerException at this line of code:

```
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the obvious candidate is that `spinner` is null, suggesting that this:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.aggiungi_ora_materia);
```

is returning null. The first thing to do is check that - log whether `spinner` is null.

Are you sure you're using the right ID? As per [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29), `findViewById` will return null if you use the wrong ID:

> Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle).
>
> Returns
> The view if found or null otherwise.

Comment: Yes i'am sure this is the spinner code of aggiungi_ora.xml (the dialog xml file)

`<Spinner android:id="@+id/aggiungi_ora_materia" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`

Comment: @barbo: I think Jon is on the right track here. Spinner is likely `null` since you're trying to inflate it from the activity's content view. However, You what you probably meant is: `Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.aggiungi_ora_materia);` - note how `findViewById(...)` is called on the custom dialog `view`, and not the activity. In other words: you're trying to inflate the spinner from the wrong layout.

Comment: I understand that the problem is that the spinner is null because it does not find the spinner in the xml, but what can i do?

Comment: @barbo: Did you try MH's idea?

Comment: Yes i use this code but it crash :(
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) **v**.findViewById(R.id.aggiungi_ora_materia);

Comment: "it crash" doesn't really provide much information. *How* does it crash?

Comment: Always by a java.lang.NullPointerException at this line of code: spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: @barbo: Ah, so it's the same problem - `findViewById` returns null? It still sounds like you might be calling `findViewById` on the wrong object. What is `v` here? (There's no such variable in your original code.)

Comment: i'm Sorry but i'm new to android developing. The v variable is the view of the click event `public void onSetup4bottone(View v)` . I understand the problem but not how to solve it :( thank for your patience

Comment: @barbo: So did you try following **exactly** what MH had written, using `view` instead of `v`?

Comment: It works! Thanks! However because i want to learn well the android development can you explain me what is the view variable?

Comment: @barbo: Look at your own code! It's the view for `aggiungi_ora`, which is where you've defined the spinner...

Comment: ops, really dumb error XD
However when i click on the spinner it crash with the error: `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window`
I think that is the same first problem, but i can't find the solution...

Comment: @barbo: No, that's a completely different exception at that point. I suggest you ask a new question with more details.